# codeigniter multi language and route not found 404

Tags: codeigniter, routes, multilingual

I am using this lib [URI-Language-Identifier](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier)

Home page works good but when I try to open any link on the site, I get the error: `page not found`

Route:

> // Language in URI

```
$route['(\w{2})/(.*)'] = '$2'; 
$route['(\w{2})'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Url

```
> $route['pro/(:any)'] = 'pro/index/$1';
```

When I open a link:

> localhost/en/pro/1

Got page not found 404
and when I trigger a link:

> `localhost/en/pro/index/1`

Page open

i want page open without index in url

```
localhost/en/pro/1
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$route['^(\w{2})/pro/(.*)$'] = 'pro/index/$2';
```

Comment: A few explanations might be in place so that everybody understands why this solves the problem.